# add semantic validator to swagger editor open source code?

Tags: javascript, validation, swagger-editor

hey guys i want to add some custom semantic  validators to swagger editor open source code

inside plugin/validate-semantic/validators i have tryed to  added customValidator.js file and i implemented a function inside that file to check if the version of the info object in the yaml file is 2.0 or 3.0.0 else it shows an error
here is my customValidator.js file content :
`

```
export const myValidator = sys => {
  return sys.validateSelectors
    .allInfos()
    .then(nodes => {
      return nodes.reduce((acc, node) => {
        const value = node.node;

        if (value.version !== '2.0' && value.version !== '3.0.0') {
          acc.push({
            level: 'error',
            message: `Unsupported Swagger version: ${value.version}`,
            path: [...node.path, 'version']
          });
        }

        return acc;
      }, []);
    });
};
```

`
and this is the plugin/validate-semantic/index.js which contain the SemanticValidatorsPlugin

```
import * as selectors from "./selectors"
import * as actions from "./actions"
import traverse from "traverse"
import {createSelector} from "reselect"
import debounce from "lodash/debounce"
import memoize from "lodash/memoize"

import * as formDataValidateActions from "./validators/form-data"
import * as schemaValidateActions from "./validators/schema"
import * as pathsValidateActions from "./validators/paths"
import * as securityValidateActions from "./validators/security"
import * as parametersValidateActions from "./validators/parameters"
import * as operationsOAS3ValidateActions from "./validators/oas3/operations"
import * as parametersOAS3ValidateActions from "./validators/oas3/parameters"
import * as componentsOAS3ValidateActions from "./validators/oas3/components"
import * as refsOAS3ValidateActions from "./validators/oas3/refs"
import * as schemasOAS3ValidateActions from "./validators/oas3/schemas"
import * as refs2and3ValidateActions from "./validators/2and3/refs"
import * as parameters2and3ValidateActions from "./validators/2and3/parameters"
import * as paths2and3ValidateActions from "./validators/2and3/paths"
import * as schemas2and3ValidateActions from "./validators/2and3/schemas"
import * as operations2and3ValidateActions from "./validators/2and3/operations"
import * as security2and3ValidateActions from "./validators/2and3/security"
import * as tags2and3ValidateActions from "./validators/2and3/tags"
// test version control 
// import * as validateInfoVersion from "./validators/2and3/version"
import * as customValidator from "./validators/2and3/customValidator"

export default function SemanticValidatorsPlugin({getSystem}) {

  const debAll = debounce((system) => system.validateActions.all(), 300)
  const traverseOnce = makeTraverseOnce(getSystem)

  return {
    fn: {
      traverse,
      traverseOnce,
      memoizedResolveSubtree: makeMemoizedResolveSubtree(getSystem())
    },
    statePlugins: {
      spec: {
        selectors: {
          jsonAsJS: createSelector(
            state => state.get("json"),
            (spec) => spec ? spec.toJS() : null
          )
        },
        wrapActions: {
          validateSpec: (ori, system) => (...args) => {
            // verify editor plugin already loaded and function is available (for tests)
            if (system.specSelectors.specOrigin) {
              const specOrigin = system.specSelectors.specOrigin()
              if (specOrigin === "editor") {
                ori(...args)
                debAll(system)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      validate: {
        selectors,
        actions: {
          ...actions,
          ...formDataValidateActions,
          ...schemaValidateActions,
          ...pathsValidateActions,
          ...securityValidateActions,
          ...parametersValidateActions,
          ...operations2and3ValidateActions,
          ...refs2and3ValidateActions,
          ...operationsOAS3ValidateActions,
          ...parametersOAS3ValidateActions,
          ...componentsOAS3ValidateActions,
          ...refsOAS3ValidateActions,
          ...schemasOAS3ValidateActions,
          ...parameters2and3ValidateActions,
          ...paths2and3ValidateActions,
          ...schemas2and3ValidateActions,
          ...security2and3ValidateActions,
          ...tags2and3ValidateActions,
          ...customValidator,
          //first validator
          // ...validateInfoVersion
        }
      },
    }
  }
}

function makeTraverseOnce(getSystem) {
  let traversers = {}
  let results = {}
  let deferred = null

  const debTraverse = debounce(() => {
    // Setup collections
    for(let name in traversers) {
      results[name] = []
    }

    const system = getSystem()

    const json = system.specSelectors.jsonAsJS()

    getSystem().fn.traverse(json)
      .forEach(function() { // Remember: this cannot be a fat-arrow function, because we need to read "this"
        for(let name in traversers) {
          const fn = traversers[name]
          const fnRes = fn(this)
          if(fnRes) {
            results[name].push(fnRes)
          }
        }
      })

    deferred.resolve(results)
    deferred = null

    traversers = {}
    results = {}
  }, 20) // 20ms might be more than enough, since most of these are called immediately (within a tick)

  const defer = () => {
    let d = {}
    d.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      d.resolve = resolve
      d.reject = reject
    })
    return d
  }

  return ({fn, name}) => {
    traversers[name] = fn
    deferred = deferred || defer()
    debTraverse()
    return deferred.promise.then( a => a[name] )
  }
}

function makeMemoizedResolveSubtree(system) {
  const cacheKeymaker = (obj, path) => {
    return `${obj.toString()} ${path.join("<>")}`
  }
  return memoize(async (obj, path, opts) => {
    const res = await system.fn.resolveSubtree(obj.toJS(), path, opts)
    return res
  }, cacheKeymaker)
}
```

but the validator dosent work
can anyone help me ?

i added a  customValidator.js  file
implemented inside it a function that checks the version of the info object inside the yaml file
imported the validator inside index.js file then added the validator in the validate section but it dosent read it can anyone help
here is the open-source code of swagger editor
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider asking in the Swagger Editor's GitHub repo https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues, you might get a better answer there.